# Assembly language 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I've a problem with Assembly 8086. I don't know how to use an 2D array. When I m using like this
`mov ar[cx][dx]` I get an error, and when I want to us `SI`and `DI` in an array it also returns an error.

Comment: It would help if you provide a little more source code, we're not clairvoyant...

Answer (score 11):

I would be very impressed in a CPU that provided array lookup semantics in its assembly language. Or rather, I would be annoyed if it meant something more important had been sacrificed.

The general way to do array lookup in assembly is by doing the calculation yourself to turn the two indexes for a 2D array into a single index for a 1D array, and adjust for the element size. For example (pseudo-code):

```
ax = cx * major_dimension
ax = ax + dx
ax = ax * element_size
ax = peek[base+ax]
```

where `major_dimension` is one of the dimensions of the 2D array (which dimension you use depends entirely on how the data is laid out in memory), `element_size` is the size of each element, `base` is the start of the array and cx/dx are the indexes you're using to access the array.

For example, if you have a 3-by-4 (`a[0-2][0-3]`) array at memory location `0x0700` and these are 32-bit integers:

```
        +--------+--------+--------+--------+
0x0700: | a[0,0] | a[0,1] | a[0,2] | a[0,3] |
        +--------+--------+--------+--------+
0x0710: | a[1,0] | a[1,1] | a[1,2] | a[1,3] |
        +--------+--------+--------+--------+
0x0720: | a[2,0] | a[2,1] | a[2,2] | a[2,3] |
        +--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

To find array element `a[n,m]`, you calculate the major index multiplied by four plus the minor index, scale it to the correct element size (4 bytes) then add the base. To find element `a[2,1]`

```
addr = base   + (n * 4 + m) * 4
     = 0x0700 + (2 * 4 + 1) * 4
     = 0x0700 + (8     + 1) * 4
     = 0x0700 + (9        ) * 4
     = 0x0700 + 36
     = 0x0700 + 0x24
     = 0x0724
```

Then that's the address you use for looking up the 1D array.

---

And, based on the comment that:

```
ar   db   3dup(3dup(0))
     mov  ar[bx][si],al
```

would work, that's not quite right (`ar[bx][si]` is masm-specific syntax equivalent to `ar[bx+si]`).

All that does is a simple addition of the `ar` address with the `bx` and `si` registers. It does *not* scale the `bx` or `si` register to take into account the major dimension and it does *not* scale the `bx+si` value for the element size. So it will only work as-is for a 2D array of *bytes* where the major dimension is 1, which I'm pretty sure would make it a 1D array :-)

To work for any case, you would first need to multiply `bx` or `si` (depending on which is being used for the major dimension) by the major dimension then both `bx` and `si` by the element size.

Comment: I know about these but my question not like this.
my Q is what is the format support in 8086 assembly. How we assign data in 2D array and how we get data form array

Comment: You can't do it in 8086. Its instruction set has no 2D array capability, just the base+offset, which allows you to do a 1D array. 2D you have to emulate yourself. Use `mul` (unigned multiply) and `add` (add) to do the calculations.

Comment: ar db 3dup(3dup(0)) just declared with every packet 0

mov ar[bx][si],al  this is worked bx as base register,these both BX,SI worked together for array

Comment: @R.K.Rahu, based-indexed-plus-displacement is not actually 2D array addressing, it's a simple additive addressing mode where you add (in your example, ar+bx+si. You _still_ need to multiply bx or si by one of the dimensions (and adjust for array element size) to get the right address.

Comment: ya I agree I v to multiply bx with column value every time whenever row insertion finish .  ar[bx][si] ( bx*0)+si for 1st row and (bx*1)+si for 2nd row
thank u very much 
then one thing If u look up this comment give me answer
difference between 9 dup(0) and 3dup(3dup(0))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clear on the exact question you're asking but are you after something like this (using base/indexed addressing mode)?

```
lea bx, array_base
mov si, array_index
mov ax, [bx][si]
```

Comment: thanks I agree and I know this but this is for 1D array
but I want 2D array assignment

Comment: @R.K.: In assembler it's all the same. Just flat, linearly addressed memory. You need to calculate the offset: array_index = y * row_size + x (and also take into account the size of the elements - this is for a byte offset) as others have mentioned.

Comment: ya I agree but I want to say that assembly compiler provided some array facility for 2D such as  ( ar[bx][si] ) this worked as for acquire value of row and column of array variable.

Answer (score 0):

This could help you.

2D arrays are stored in a memory just like 1D array but represent it as having rows and columns.

Below is the code to declare the 2D array which is stored in memory linearly.

Like this:

```
                +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
          index | arr[0][0]| arr[0][1]| arr[0][2]| arr[0][3]| arr[0][4]| arr[1][0]| arr[1][1]| 
                +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
         value  |    0     |    1     |    2     |    3     |    4     |    10    |    11    |
                +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
 memory address | 1000     | 1004     | 1008     | 1012     | 1016     | 1020     | 1024     |
                +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Here each row have 4 entries and 5 columns.

Now if i want to locate value 11 ,arr[1][1] row 1 col 1 ,then the memory address will be 1024. To locate this entry first I have to calculate row index then column index.

**Calculating row index:**

So each row have 5 entries each of 4 bytes therefore each row will be of 4*5=20 bytes. Entry 11 is in row index 1 so 1*20 = 20 which will be at row 1.

**Calculating column index:**

After that entry 11 is in the column index 1 so 1*4= 4 which be at column index 1. We multiply it by 4 because we have declared it as DWORD which is of 4 bytes.

At last just add the results (row index + col index) 20+4 = 24. When we add this to the memory address of first entry we will be jumped to entry 11

i.e: 1000+24 = 1024

> .data
>
> arr  DWORD  0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ; This is declaration of 2D array having 4 rows, 5 cols each entry takes 4 bytes because its a DWORD
>
> ```
>       DWORD 10,11,12,13,14
>
>       DWORD 20,21,22,23,24
>
>       DWORD 30,31,32,33,34
> ```
>
> ROWSIZE EQU   SIZEOF arr    ; its a named constant which means each row is having 20 bytes. In each row there are 5 cols means 5 entries and each entry is of 4 bytes so 4*5 = 20.
>
> .code
>
> mov ebx, 2*ROWSIZE  ; row index = 2
>
> mov esi, 3  ; col index = 3
>
> mov eax, arr[ebx+esi*4] ; EAX = arr[2][3], Here when we call arr[0] it will be entry 0 so entry 11 will be arr[24]. It means skip 24 bytes from the starting memory address of the array.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you provide some addional infors about your code?